# iphone iCloud - how can we upload picture from our app to iCloud.

Tags: iphone, icloud, icloud-api

i am new to icloud. i am working on an app. in my app i want to take backup of pictures  to iCloud server. but i don't want to get those images back to my iPhone.

is this possible. how can be it done. i am new to iCloud. Please help me. any good tutorial or demo code.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please read [this](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/) official documentation may help you and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) is the beginner tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link of the tutorial for the same .

[upload  images over the iCloud](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/add-an-icloud-photo-gallery-to-your-app-with-mticloudphotogallery-library/)

I hope you may get good idea form this

Comment: its developer is saying this :-----I’ve lost several months of time arguing with the Apple Review Team about this type of using iCloud for storing photos and it seems they were not convinced that iCloud can be used for storage of data from developers. So, if you are following this post, please re-consider the whole dev guideline document from the Apple Dev Center, and use the code cautiously.